# Gulp Watch is not working in gulp 4.0.2 until run gulp again

Tags: css, sass, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

In my gulfile.js, I'm using watch to compile scss files to css files. It runs without error and when I run gulp in powershell, it says that it is watching, but whenever I define a style in my scss file, it doesn't affect the css file which is created and I have to stop gulp and run it again. Actually, it's not watching carefully ! 
Here is my code. 
Thanks for any help.

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var minifyCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var changed = require("gulp-changed");
var { task, series } = require("gulp");

var SCSS_SRC = "./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss";
var SCSS_DEST = "./src/Assets/css";


task("compile_scss", function() {


 gulp
  .src(SCSS_SRC) 
  .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError)) 
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST)) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST)); 
});


task("watch_scss", function() {
 gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, series(["compile_scss"]));
});

task("default", series("watch_scss"));
```

Comment: Looks weird to me that your watch task is using `compile_scss`, which does minification. Not sure if that could cause any problems, but I would create a new task for watch, which uses only minimal required setup, e.g `gulp  .src(SCSS_SRC).pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError)).pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));`

Comment: I want  my compile_scss to be watched. @Gabriel Lima solution solved the problem. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem be solved, as @Gabriel mentioned and according [this link](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task), I changed my code to this and the problem solved. But when I ran npm start, the watch stopped working; Therefore, I installed "concurrently" through npm and changed my start in package.json as mentioned here:

```js
npm install concurrently

"start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start \" \"gulp \"",
```

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var minifyCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var changed = require("gulp-changed");
var { task, series } = require("gulp");

var SCSS_SRC = "./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss";
var SCSS_DEST = "./src/Assets/css";


function compile_scss() {
 return gulp
  .src(SCSS_SRC)
  .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
}

function watch_scss() {
 gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, series(compile_scss));
}

exports.default = series(watch_scss);
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed a return. The gulp doesn't know the task has completed. In your case you have to return the stream. Here is how your code should be:

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var minifyCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var changed = require("gulp-changed");
var { task, series } = require("gulp");

var SCSS_SRC = "./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss";
var SCSS_DEST = "./src/Assets/css";

function compile_scss() {
    return gulp
        .src(SCSS_SRC) 
        .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError)) 
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST)) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST)); 
}


function watch_scss() {
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, series(compile_scss));
}

exports.default = series(watch_scss);
```

I also took the liberty of removing the "task()"s since

> Reminder: This API isn't the recommended pattern anymore - export your tasks.

as said [here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task).

Comment: Also, those "series()" are not needed since it is only one task.

Comment: You saved my day Gabriel, great solution. I didn't know about that reminder. Thank you for the link also.